# Outlook Web Add In -

Tags: c#

I have a COM Outlook Add-In that I am converting to Outlook Web Add-in. I want to disable the ICON if the selected email does not have an attachment; if multiple attachments, provide the user an option to select one attachment. I have this working in the COM project, but it's Windows based, so I can open Windows Form with the attachment to be selected. I am new to Outlook Web 
Add-In and not sure how to do this with the HTML/JS/XML. I am using Visual Studio 2019 - language c#

I have create a Visual Studio Outlook Web Add-in Project - I have the html, js and xml files - not sure how to disable the add-in icon if the selected email does not have an attachment -

I am having problem with the code format - here is an example with current cdoe calling .cs method.

```html
<button id="PushToSFDCExplorer" size="large" label="Push To Salesforce" 
        getEnabled="isEnabledOnExplorer" getImage="GetButtonImage" 
        onAction="PushToSalesforce_Click" />
```

I would like to know the best way to handle enabling the add-in icon if selected email has an attachment - if multiple attachment, allow the user to select one attachment - not sure how to do this in Outlook Web Add-in since it appears to be xml/js driven.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Where is your code?

Comment: Here is my html code:

Comment: my code exceeds the allow length

Comment: @Creoabraham You can hit "edit" under your original question and add your code there. There shouldn't be a limit for your question. ;^)